# Background doesn´t fill the whole page because of sticky footer

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want a background picture on my React app, that fills the whole page, but the sticky footer prohibits the background from reaching out the whole page:

[image: 1]

I think the problem is, that the sticky footer has a margin-top: auto, what hinders the background from the content of the page to reach all the way down to the footer.

Here is my App.css:

```
    .App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #686868;
}
```

And thats my Footer.css:

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #212529;
  color: #c7c7c7;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Here is the content of the page:

```
.about {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Problem: When I set the height in the .about to any vh heigt, it won't fit exactly, I always get white stripes ether on the top or the bottom of the footer.

Comment: the background-clip: padding-box; doesn´t matter, it has no effect, i forgot to delete that line

Comment: You can always [edit] your post...

Comment: Where is background-image? please show code HTML about to problem.